# Should the DBContext file get updated automatically using EF 6.0.1 and ASP.NET 4 Code-First?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I create a new Model should the DBContext get updated automatically or is my entity framework broken?

```
 using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For example, if I add the Genres class, should it update the MusicStoreEntities class with this automatically?

```
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
```

It's NOT currently working like that in my project and I'm wondering if something is broken OR if I just have to manually add the above line.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't automatically update.  Consider using Code First Migrations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591621.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Actually, I am using Code First. Thanks for the link. I've been there several times trying to wrap my head around this. So, I'm using code-first and add a new Model, then I'll need to add the line to the Entities class if I want EF to create a new table for me right?

Comment: The point here isn't the Code First part, but the *Migrations* part.  It's a standard way of updating the database schema as you update your code first models.  Adding models, updating data types, renaming properties, all are handled under migrations.  These changes will not automatically prorogate.

Comment: Actually that's why I finally after a week of struggling with this asked the question here.  My migration wasn't picking up my new model. I assumed it would get picked up and create the new table in the database.  It wasn't until I manually added it to the entities class that the table got created.  Then after that all changes were picked up. I'm just looking for a little more clarification on that. Thanks!